# Spyder standalone environment

Tags: python, conda, spyder, environment

I intend to install Spyder standalone on a Mac. (In addition I will use conda to manage my environments, and point Spyder to the environment I want to use.)
Now, suppose I want to manage things in the environment where Spyder itself is installed (the standalone installation), for example install packages there. How do I do it? In a conda environment I could do something like this:

```
conda activate myenv
```

and work there. But since Spyder is a standalone environment, how do I access it?

In addition, since this standalone installation goes into "applications" in the mac, will it notify me when a new version of Spyder is available and offer to update (as in other applications?

### EDIT:

I found some contradicting-looking information about this. According to [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/14419) I should probably not install packages there (and maybe it's impossible).
but [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-most-common-problem--using-newly-installed-packages-inside-spyder)
in the first bullet point at the bottom of the page, it says "In order for the Variable Explorer to be able to display the built-in editors for specific data types (Numpy array, Pandas Series/DataFrame, etc) the corresponding optional Spyder dependencies (Numpy, Pandas, etc) need to be installed in Spyder's environment".

Comment: I ran into this problem awhile back. I had to install spyder in every environment I wanted to use it in, then open spyder from within the environment from the terminal. Not sure if there is a way to have one spyder that switches between environments.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "standalone installation". Is it not also a Conda environment? For Jupyter, I have a dedicated environment with `jupyter` and `nb_conda_kernels` installed, and this is whence I run Jupyter. When I want to update it, I run `conda update -n jupyter jupyter nb_conda_kernels`. That is, I specify the environment in which I want the update done.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @merv I am talking about an actual standalone installation where Spyder is installed in its own environment unrelated to conda. See here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#standalone-installers-ref
it's like a Spyder application which I can launch (it appears in mac "applications") and connect to a conda environment using a Spyder kernel. However, I found some information that looks contradictory to me, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) About your questions:

> Now, suppose I want to manage things in the environment where Spyder itself is installed (the standalone installation), for example install packages there. How do I do it?

It's not possible to install any package in our standalone installers. That's by design in order for users to not break them.

If you need to use other packages that don't come with them (e.g. Scikit-learn or Seaborn), you need to create a new environment, install them there and connect Spyder to that environment. That process is better described in [these instructions](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer).

> since this standalone installation goes into "applications" in the mac, will it notify me when a new version of Spyder is available and offer to update (as in other applications?

We don't offer that functionality yet, but we'll try to do it in the future.

> but here in the first bullet point at the bottom of the page, it says "In order for the Variable Explorer to be able to display the built-in editors for specific data types (Numpy array, Pandas Series/DataFrame, etc) the corresponding optional Spyder dependencies (Numpy, Pandas, etc) need to be installed in Spyder's environment".

All optional dependencies needed to explore Numpy arrays and Pandas dataframes are provided in the installers.